# c# returning only requested property from an object

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api, odata, nest

I am creating an api, where the request will specify which property is required in the response. This could be any properties in a class.

How to dynamically return the properties requested from a class?

I have a simple class as:

```
public class Example {
  public string Attr1 {get;set;}
  public string Attr2 {get;set;}
  public string Attr3 {get;set;}
  public string Attr4 {get;set;}
}
```

Currently the asp.net webapi returning the following dto object if i request Attr1 and Attr2:

```
public class ExampleDto
{
    public string Attr1 { get; set; }
    public string Attr2 { get; set; }
}
```

How to make this dynamic so that i can return any property requested i.e Attr2 and Attr3?

I am not using EntityFramework datasource. I am using NEST framework to query against ElasticSearch.

Can anyone help how to solve my problem? If OData is the solution, how to use OData with ElasticSearch

Thanks

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve], so we can move this problem from the abstract to the concrete.

Comment: Look at [OData](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/)